# jQuery + Perl CGI to vb.net transition

Tags: jquery, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, perl, web-applications

I've been developing oracle database-heavy "web applications" forever by building my html by hand, adding some jquery to handle ajax requests (html inserts for forms processing etc), and always did my server side stuff in perl cgi. I really love how easy it is to read some form input, execute some select statements through dbi, and generate HTML to be inserted by the jquery request. That's a web application to me.

However, my new boss builds everything in visual studio 2010, vb.net for web application development. That's how much I can describe it. So, for work reasons, I now need to start developing in vb.net so it can be collectively maintained, and I'm just seeking advice on where to start learning/how to approach this.

I'm thinking I need to learn [how to write cgi applications in vb.net](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239588) , and continue with client-side scripting (jQuery) handled by server-side CGI processing by combiled vb.net exe's, maybe.

We're moving heavily to mobile applications and really need to reduce client-side processing load. Is there any advantage to my boss' method?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for programmers.stackexchange. Although their [“What can I ask here?”](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)-page forbids “which technology is better”-question, this does not pit VB.net vs. Perl, but asks (1.) for pointers on learning VB/.NET and (2.) if his boss' method is advantageous (using IDEs and graphical tools instead of hand-coding), unifying the company technology stack, and (3.) if offloading client-side calculations from JS to CGI scripts is a good idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Is there any advantage to my boss' method?*

At least two:

- force you to abandon an **obsolete language** (yes a little trolling inside ;)) and an **obsolete technology** (CGI)
- open you to the (not always so) great world of **.Net**

This is really important from a **maintainability** point of view: you'll find a bunch of cheap and skilled developers for .Net but less and less for Perl (experience talking :))

You could ask confirmation to your boss but I guess "*vb.net for web application development*" means **VB.Net + ASP.Net**

I don't know what's your decision-making power but you should convince your boss to:

- **use C# instead of VB.Net** for future developments because it has a greater community (just have a look at the books on the .Net technos, less and less take the trouble to target VB.Net :( ); and you can **use both in the same ASP.Net application** so you can develop new modules in C# and interact with the older written in VB.Net
- use the **[MVC sub-framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc)** of ASP.Net, not the **WebForms** part (an old school technology too)

For client-side, **jQuery** is a good tool if you build simple apps, otherwise you'll need a more high-level framework like **[Angular.JS](http://angularjs.org/)** to ease development.

Comment: Calling Perl an obsolete language isn't trolling, it's just a lack of knowledge about what's going on in Perl in 2013; that's OK, though, I probably have similar misconceptions about .NET ;-)

On the other hand, calling CGI obsolete is 100% correct -- even Perl has moved on! On balance, you got an upvote.

Comment: @JamesGreen: I know that Perl is alive and still developed but the community has considerably reduced and few new projects, compared to other technologies, are started. As an illustration I've worked in a bank where Perl was still used for only one reason: the boss really knew it and liked it, so while nobody except him knew it before, a lot of people had to work with it, but outside of his sphere of influence Perl has completely disappeared replaced by other technos like ASP.net (both C# and VB.Net), PHP and some Ruby. So yes Perl is a great language but unfortunately has passed its chance :)

Comment: @JamesGreen: oops downvote ... seems like everybody is not as moderate as you are ;)

Comment: @Pragmateek thanks so much for your answer, I don't consider it trolling as long as it's the truth. Our apps are pretty simple, just some 8 column HTML tables with some prefilled info and some additional <input> fields with values to be collected and passed to the server side script. So- what would you suggest I start developing the server side code in? How do I return stuff to jQuery without writing to stdout?

Comment: @JamesGreen I'm really interested in modern perl, but I may be forced into using vb.net- what perl options do I have? Thanks guys!

Comment: If you want to find out more about Perl "since CGI", the magic words to search for are 'PSGI', 'Moose', and then take your pick of the modern web frameworks: Dancer, Catalyst, Mojolicious, I've probably forgotten some.  Also, as @Pragmateek says, if you're stuck in .NET land because your boss insists (his perogative, natch) -- push for C#. VB's as dead as people claim Perl is ;-)

Comment: @user1257458: if your UI are really simple yes jQuery fits perfectly, no need for Angular, it would rather add complexity. :) As for the server side you should use ASP.Net MVC: you first design your template for your view, typically using Razor (it's very good and can be embedded in other type of application (tested and approved by yours truly ;)), then you merge the template with the model (your data) and this is the combination of both which is output to the client. I think it's a good thing because it will force you to better structure your code separating view and model.

Comment: @user1257458: if you want an entry-point to only output some data (i.e. a web-service) you can get rid of a view and simply "write to stdout"; have a look at JSON to structure your data, and map with your business objects but if you use XML or CSV or your custom format it's good too if it's simple. Simpler is better. :)

Comment: @JamesGreen: +1 for comparing VB.Net and Perl, that's so true. :(